# Google Sheets OnEdit script: copy value from specific columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We are using Google sheets for tracking attendance. Previously, the teachers were entering P, T, or A (for present, tardy, absent) for each period. I would still like users to have the option to enter a value for each period in a week, however it would be a great time saver if they could enter one value for the whole day.

What I'd like is that if a value is entered into any one of the "0" periods (green columns) with a "P" or "A" (data validation limits those options) an **OnEdit** function would copy that same letter ("P" or "A") to the following 8 columns *and then delete the original value*. (without the deletion the totals on the far right columns will be off).  I would not want the **OnEdit** to be activitated based on edits in any of the non-green columns.

I will eventually have several tabs, each one a different week, but each exactly the same... so I'm thinking the function should work within whatever the activesheet is.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NKIdNY4k66r0zhJeFv8jYYoIwuTq0tCWlWin5GO_YtM/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote some code to get you started with your project. (I am also a teacher) You will have to make some changes based on what you are going for and it can probably be optimised to run faster. Good luck!

```
function onEdit(e) {

  //create an array of the columns that will be affected
  var allColumns = [2, 10];

  //get the number values of the column and row
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var row = e.range.getRow();

  //get the A1 notation of the editted cell for clearing it out
  var cell = e.range.getA1Notation();

  //only run if the cell is in a column in the allColumns array
  if(allColumns.indexOf(col) > -1) {

    //run the for loop for the next 8 cells
    for(var i = col + 1; i < col + 9; i++) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, i).setValue(e.value);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).setValue('');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works great for the first set of columns.  For the other sets of columns (days), I just copied and pasted it with simple edits to the allColumns section at the beginning.  Thanks for the help.  Works perfectly!

Comment: Just change the numbers in the allColumns array to coincide with the columns that are being edited. Column B is 2, Column J is 10, etc...

Comment: Ah, i see in your demo sheet you just copied the snippet for each specific column. You should be able to put all of the columns into the array without duplicating code.